# "Like button" plugin of facebook

Tags: facebook

I just included the like button plugin of facebook on my site. Now, I want to send messages or send an update to those who liked my page. How to do so? Please help!

Regards,
Sanket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your wall on your facebook page. Depending on what settings your page "fans" have, they will see your wall update on their news feed. I think there is also a link on the left side of your page [if you're logged in as an admin] to send a message to all people who like the page.